# Java, Load native library inside classpath

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, classloader

I have the following distribution

```
.__bin
|   |__start.sh
|
|__lib
    |__Main.jar
    |__Utility.jar
    |__lib.so
```

*Main.jar* contains main method, in which I would like to access native functions provided by the *lib.so* bundled in the distribution. *start.sh* simply sets the classpath and bootstraps java.

What is the best approach to load the *lib.so* library inside the application? I am aware of two methods:

- System.load(*absolute path*)
- System.loadLibrary(*name*)

Former requires the absolute path of the library in the file system, latter requires setting the application specific *java.library.path* JVM argument. Which is better solution in this case? Would setting the library path in the *start.sh* script possibly break something? How could I get the absolute file system path of the library for the former solution?

Answer (score 3):

The `load()` method requires the complete path name of the library as an argument. For example, on a Solaris system you might write:

```
System.load("/home/me/libs/libmylib.so");
```

to load the **libmylib.so** library in the `/home/me/libs` directory.

Using the `load()` method is system-dependent because it uses a `pathname` to load the library and pathnames are usually system-dependent. Thus, `loadLibrary()` is sometimes a better choice. However, dynamically loadable libraries are system-dependent in nature so the use of `load()` may not compromise system-independence any more than the act of loading the library itself.

The `loadLibrary()` method requires just the name of a to load:

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

The `loadLibrary()` method searches for the library. The search performed by `loadLibrary()` depends on the system you are running on, but typically, it searches the directories listed in one of your environment variables set up to that purpose.

You can explicitly specify your absolute path.

Apart from system independence, there are no real differences security wise.

**References** :

1) https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35724/security-implications-of-javas-system-load-vs-system-loadlibrary

2) https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am not missing anything, isn't setting System.load the best approach? Your lib.so is not going to change since you have it in your structure. If you would want to give control to the end user to load the native/shared library from elsewhere have an optional parameter in start.sh. Else use the System.load().Just make sure to check the type of OS, since you will be having the different formats for file paths.